# Don't validate if there is no edit - Laravel 7

Tags: laravel

I have an edit profile form where the inputs have values assigned by the user in the past. The problem I'm facing is that when the user does not change these values the validation mechanism of laravel throughs an error, e.g if `username:Gass` is not changed then the user clicks on submit and it's faced with the `error: The username has already been taken.`

How can I skip the validation if the input value has not been edited?

**My validation**

```
$request->validate([
            'username' => ['nullable','max:15','unique:users', 'regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$/'],
            'email' => ['nullable','string', 'email', 'max:50', 'unique:users'],
            'about' => ['nullable','max:300'],
            'location' => ['nullable','max:30','regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9., ]+$/'],
            'website' => ['nullable','max:40','regex:/^((?:https?\:\/\/|www\.)(?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)*[-a-z0-9]+.*)$/'],
            'avatar' => ['nullable','image','mimes:jpg,png,jpeg,gif','max:500','dimensions:min_width=100,min_height=100'],
            'twitter' => ['nullable','max:15', 'regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/'],
            'youtube' => ['nullable','max:50', 'regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$/'],
]);
```

Comment: @N69S I saw that answer before writing the question. It did not help.

Comment: Wierd, cause it is the right answer, replace your unique rule with `unique:users,email,'.auth()->user()->email.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can force a `Unique` rule to ignore a given ID. See the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-unique). Scroll to section: **Forcing A Unique Rule To Ignore A Given ID.**

In your example, something like this should suffice:

```
$request->validate([
    ...,
    'username' => ['nullable','max:15',Rule::unique('users')->ignore(auth()->id()), 'regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$/'],
]);
```

the `ignore()` method accepts 2 parameters, the first being the value to check for, the second parameter accepts the column of the table to check, but defaults to `id`.

Assuming your user is logged in here.

Comment: I saw the documentation but I did not know how to implement it. Thanks @EricLandheer

Answer (score 2):

in update, you must ignore that item for unique validation rule like

```
'username' => ['nullable','max:15',Rule::unique('users')->ignore($this->id, 'id'), 'regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$/'],
```

Comment: Thanks @Prospero, why did you write `$this->id` ? It doesn't seem to work with it.

Comment: is as example, this must compare the item or model instance id to be ignored. If is the authenticated user is auth()->id(), if is a retrieved data from db must be $model->id or another assigned to public property like $this->item->id